# Django real-time game backend

Tags: django, node.js, real-time, twisted, tornado

I plan to make an online game. It will be a full real-time during play. For my website backend I have used Django. Database and other things are almost done. What is the best way to make user client side and server side backend for play in realtime? As I use Django it would be nice to have it in Python.
We plan that there will be minimum ~1000 online players all the time.
Twisted/Tornado/Node.js or maybe something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to answer your question (not enough details in your question) but using django to power a webdriven is something I'm personally interested in, so best of luck to ya!

Comment: You should definitely take a look at gevent

Comment: Not sure what you are asking - since you didn't provide any details of your game. What is the game mechanism? Turn based? "Realtime" means different things.

Comment: @burhan It will be a full real-time game. 2 players playing game in the same time with their own teams. It won't be a turn based game. I need full realtime support.

Answer (score 1):

Tornado is very light and pretty nice in my opinion. You could integrate it with Django in various ways -- e.g. [Integrate Tornado in Django](http://geekscrap.com/2010/02/integrate-tornado-in-django/), [Integrating Django with Tornado's web server](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/8d1b7f514ef4e88e?hl=en&pli=1) -- or just run it alongside Django behind whatever web server you use.

Node is so fun that you might tire of Django. :-)

Comment: In addition, a messaging backend is crucial to off load tasks. Celery + RabbitMQ seems to be the current fashion; but ZeroMQ is very popular as well.

Comment: This answer has little or nothing to do with the question, which is overly broad.  Stackoverflow is about providing technical information, not advertising.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep separately Django - which is used for general site functions, and Tornado - which is used for realtime data. I think you should use some Redis to store/read data and communicate between django and tornado, so prevent using database access directly from tornado.

Answer (score 0):

Developing your own backend server sounds as interesting project.
But from my experience it becomes a very significant of your R&D effort.

It starts with developing core backend components, dealing with servers, installs, patches, security issues and more. 
On top of it, you will need to create admin systems to manage your player, levels, xp, integration to stores and more... and then, you have the reports (installs, retention, etc'...)

I would strongly recommend using existing backend platforms.